# Evaluating a complicated limit

Tags: limits

Okay so I was solving some problems on differentiability and I came across this stubborn limit . I'm out of ideas about how to tackle this , would really love some help.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -3^{-}}\frac{-5a \sin(\pi x)+5b(x^2-9)\cos(\pi x)-(x^2-9)}{-30(x+3)^2}$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are some finite value constants .

Someone please help.

Comment: can you use L'Hospital?

Comment: I can , but would really not prefer it . There must be a better way , you know ?

Comment: How can you say that ? I'm pretty sure the limiting value would come in terms of the two constants.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire no, it isn't.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Actually the constant play a fundamental role, since according to their sign, the limit can take a different sign. And the limit is not zero!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $x+3=t$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -3^{-}}\frac{-5a \sin(\pi x)+5b(x^2-9)\cos(\pi x)-(x^2-9)}{-30(x+3)^2}=\lim_{t\to 0^-}\frac{-5 a \sin(\pi t-3\pi)+t(t-6)(5b\cos(\pi t-3\pi)-1)}{-30 t^2}=
$$
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^-}\frac{5 a \sin(\pi t)+t(t-6)(-5b\cos(\pi t)-1)}{-30 t^2}=
$$
$$
=\lim_{t\to 0^-}\frac{5 a \pi t(\sin(\pi t)/(\pi t))+t(t-6)(-5b\cos(\pi t)-1)}{-30 t^2}\ .
$$
Now you use the standard fact that $\sin(\pi t)/(\pi t)\to 1$, and that $\cos(\pi t)\to 1$ to conclude that your limit is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^-}\frac{5 a \pi t+t(t-6)(-5b-1)}{-30 t^2}\ .
$$
You note that the numerator goes as $\sim t (5a\pi+30b+6)$, therefore the whole fraction goes as $\sim \frac{5a\pi+30b+6}{-30}\frac{1}{t}\to\infty$
($+\infty$ or $-\infty$ depending on whether the combination $-5a\pi-30b-6$ is negative or positive).

Comment: The limit has to have a finite value , according to the question and my teacher .

Comment: If there is no typo in what you have written, then I'd disagree (and Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha agree with me...)

Comment: Hmm , strange . Thanks for the help though !

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo If you base your ideas on Wolfram Alpha, then you're wrong a priori.

Comment: @HenryTuring I based my ideas on the derivation above. Any suggestion on where my derivation is wrong?

Comment: Not a single error, actually! :D I wonder then why my Mathematica software (the serious one, not Alpha), doesn't specify the infinity. Bug? Uff. By the way I forgot an $x$ whilst computing by hands, lol.

Comment: @Tanuj your limit would only be finite if the original denominator were $-30 (x+3)$, and not $-30 (x+3)^2$.

Comment: Yeah I know that , the question is correct though. Thanks for helping man ! Really appreciate it !